# Casting .getClass() to a type parameter

Tags: java, generics

I have a generic method in which I need to obtain the class of the parameter:

```
public static<S> void doSomething(S inst) {
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Class<? extends S> cls = (Class<? extends S>) inst.getClass();
  // do something with 'cls' and with 'inst'...
}
```

As it turns out, from the compiler's type system point of view, `.getClass()` returns a `Class<?>` hence the down-cast to `Class<? extends S>` which is an *unchecked* dow-cast.

My question is as follows: in what circumstance can this down-cast be unsafe?

IIUC, all call-sites to this methods must pass a value for the `inst` parameter which is of static (compile-time) type S. The dynamic (run-time) type, D, of the value must be either S or a subtype thereof. Thus inst.getClass() will return the `Class<D>` object which, given that `D` is a subtype of `S`, should be assignable to `Class<? extends S>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in what circumstance can this down-cast be unsafe?

The return type of `inst.getClass()` is `Class<? extends |X|>`, where `|X|` is the erasure of the compile-time type of the expression `inst`. Here, `|X|` is the erasure of `S` which is `Object`. That's why it's `Class<?>` and not `Class<? extends S>`.

The reason why the erasure is necessary is that `S` could potentially be a parameterized type, but only reified types should be used in the type argument of `Class`, as `Class` objects only represent reified types. For example, you could pass in `inst` being an `ArrayList<String>`, but it's not really safe to get a `Class<? extends ArrayList<String>>`.

Why is it unsafe to have a `Class<? extends ArrayList<String>>`? Well, for example, you could use its `.cast()` method to cast anything into an `ArrayList<String>` without any warnings. But runtime type checks like `.cast()` can only check reified types (the `Class` object itself only represents a reified type); they cannot check the type arguments (which do not exist at runtime). Therefore, with `.cast()` you would effectively be doing an unchecked cast without a warning, which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will help you, but I tried to find an example situation when this class cast may be dangerous.

```
public static <S> void doSomething(S inst, Consumer<S> newInstConsumer) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    inst = (S) new Object();                                        // just a line of wrong code here
    Class<? extends S> cls = (Class<? extends S>) inst.getClass();  // and if we don't check here
    S newInstance = cls.newInstance();
    newInstConsumer.accept(newInstance);                            // this code fails only here
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main(String... args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    doSomething(new HelloWorldPrinter(), HelloWorldPrinter::print);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. This indeed illustrates the loophole but it requires at least one more unchecked cast (that is: `inst = (S) new Object`).